# Python adding more to a variable then written in the code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a simple program in python that shows me the numbers 1.0, 1.1 up to 2. This is the code

```
test = 1.0

while True:
  print(test)
  test += 0.1
  if test > 2.1:
    break
```

Output:

```
1.0
1.1
1.2000000000000002
1.3000000000000003
1.4000000000000004
1.5000000000000004
1.6000000000000005
1.7000000000000006
1.8000000000000007
1.9000000000000008
2.000000000000001
```

Expected output:

```
1.0
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5
1.6
1.7
1.8
1.9
2.0
```

Comment: You can round what you print with `print(round(test, 1))`

Comment: See the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#floating-point-arithmetic-issues-and-limitations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use just float precision

```
print(f'{test:.1f}')
```

You don't need to use it while `True` or `break`. Use instead

```
test = 1.0
while test <= 2.1:
    print(f'{test:.1f}')
    test += 0.1
```

**UPDATE:**
Set your own precitation how much you want. Nomarlly you can set upto 15 point precitation order.
Example you want to divide `test = 22/7`:

```
print(f'{test:.2f}') -> 3.14
print(f'{test:.2f}') -> 3.142
print(f'{test:.2f}') -> 3.1428
...............................
print(f'{test:.15f}') -> 3.142857142857143
```

Comment: How would it be if I wanted to do it like 1.00 instead of 1.0

Comment: @Solpip update it to `print(f'{test:.2f}')`

Answer (score 1):

Printing a float with one decimal place outputs the float with one digit after the decimal point. For example, printing `3.14159` with `3.1`. Use `str.format()`,  with `"{:.1f}"` as `str`

```
test = 1.0

while True:
  print("{:.1f}".format(test))
  test += 0.1
  if test > 2.1:
    break
```

Output :

```
1.0
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5
1.6
1.7
1.8
1.9
2.0
```